# Polynomial of Trig Functions

Tags: functions, trigonometry, special-functions, graphing-functions

Let
$f(x)=\cos(x)$ and 
$g(x)=x^3-x^2-6x$
Has anyone investigated about the shape of $f(g(x))$?
It's like a wave function, but the roots converge as $|x|$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

here is your graph of $f(g(x))$.

[image]

what do you want else, your question is not clear!

Comment: I think the OP want to know how does the polynomial $g$ affect the shape of $f\circ g$.

Comment: It's because |g'(x)| approaces infinity as x approaches infinity. As this happens, the period of f(g(x)) approaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this Desmos.com link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a5ldrlyskp) (open in a new tab) to investigate graphs of the form

$$f(x)=\cos(g(x))$$

where

$$ g(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $$

by changing the values of the coefficients to see the effect on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $f$ are

$$\pm\frac\pi2+2k\pi.$$

Obviousy, the function $g$, which is of the cubic type, reaches these values faster and faster for growing $x$, as it is super-linear.

The roots of $f(g(x))$ are obtained by solving the cubic equation

$$g(x)=x^3-x^2-6x=\pm\frac\pi2+2k\pi$$ which lead to a nasty expression that I spare you. For large $x$, you can approximate as

$$x^3\approx\pm\frac\pi2+2k\pi$$ or

$$x\approx\sqrt[3]{\pm\frac\pi2+2k\pi}\propto\sqrt[3]{k}.$$

To get an intuitive understanding of the curve behavior, you can see it as a stretched version of a cosinusoid, by the function $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! You led me to the right direction!:)